# Maximums for a function defined with a integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, maxima-minima

The senoidal integral function it's defined like
$$S_{i}= \int_{0}^x \frac{\sin t}{t}dt.$$
Because, $\frac{\sin t}{t} \rightarrow 1$ when $t \rightarrow 0$, then $Si(x)$ is well defined for all $t$ and is continuous.

a) Draw the graph for $Si$

b) For wich $x$ this function have local maximums?

c) Find the coordinates for the  first inflextion points on the right of the origin.

Solution for b). For the test of first and second derivate plus the First Theorem of Calculus we have that
$$Si'(t)= \frac{\sin t} {t}$$
and $$Si''(t)= \frac{ t\cos t-\sin t }{t^{2}}.$$
So, $Si'(t) =0 \iff \frac{\sin t} {t} =0 \iff \sin t=0 \iff t=\pi n$, for $n \in \mathbb{Z} \backslash{0}$. Then, $$Si''(\pi n) = \frac{\pi n cos(\pi n) - \sin(\pi n)}{(\pi n)^{2}}=\frac{\cos \pi n}{\pi n}$$
$t$ is a maximum local point for $Si(x)$ if $Si''(t)<0$, and this happen when $\frac{\cos \pi n}{\pi n}<0$. We have two cases

- **Case 1**. If $n>0$ then $\pi n>0$ and $\cos \pi n<0$, so $t= (2k-1)\pi$ for $k=1,2,...$.
- **Case 2**. If $n<0$ then $\pi n <0$ and $\cos \pi n >0$, so $t=-2\pi k$ for $k=1,2,...$.

In conclusion, $Si(x)$ have for local maximum points $x= (2k-1)\pi$ and $x=-2\pi k$ for $k=0,1,2,...$.

Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right. What about the inflection point ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  For inflection point we have that $Si''(t)=0$ and  $Si'''(t) \neq 0$. 
The $Si(t)=0$ say that $t \cos t - \sin t=0$ so $t= \frac{\sin t}{\cos t}$. 
And we have that $S'''(t)= \frac{-t^{3}\sin t + t^{2}\cos t - t \sin t}{t^{4}}$.
I don't se how calculate $t$.

Comment: Solving $t \cos t - \sin t=0$ is the most interesting part but there is no explicit solution. You will learn that later. Good job. Cheers :-)